# getting module error in django FW

Tags: python, django

getting following error of opening url  127.0.0.1:8000  which says no module go."jaiho.apps.homepage.urls"

but my dir structure has that module present

No idea how the flow in django.

> ```
> mkp@mkp-Vostro-2520:~**/Desktop/DJFW/jaiho/jaiho/apps/homepage**$ ls -ltr
> total 28
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mkp mkp   0 Apr 24 23:18 __init__.py
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mkp mkp  57 Apr 24 23:18 models.py
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mkp mkp  60 Apr 24 23:18 tests.py
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mkp mkp  63 Apr 24 23:18 admin.py
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mkp mkp 158 Apr 24 23:30 views.py
> -rw-r--r-- 1 mkp mkp 147 Apr 24 23:32 __init__.pyc
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 mkp mkp 335 Apr 24 23:55 urls.pyc
> -rwxrwxr-x 1 mkp mkp 115 Apr 24 23:56 urls.py
> mkp@mkp-Vostro-2520:~/Desktop/DJFW/jaiho/jaiho/apps/homepage$ pwd
> /home/mkp/Desktop/DJFW/jaiho/jaiho/apps/homepage
> ```

**content of urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *
urlspatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^$','jaiho.jaiho.apps.homepage.views.index'),

)
```

**Error**

```
> ImportError at /

No module named jaiho.apps.homepage.urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named jaiho.apps.homepage.urls

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/mkp/Desktop/DJFW/jaiho',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Thu, 24 Apr 2014 18:29:59 +0000
```

Comment: Try taking out the first `'jaiho'`. `(r'^$','jaiho.apps.homepage.views.index'),`

Comment: didn't worked...gave some other error